# aws s3 node js sdk method generatePutUrl returns differnt results for localhost and deployment on heroku

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, heroku, amazon-s3, image-uploading

I am trying to manage direct file upload to S3 according to [heroku recomendations](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3-upload-node)

1. first one need to generate presigned URL at ones server
2. use this url in client to direct upload of image from browser to S3 bucket

and finally manage to works it locally.
but when I tried to deploy server on heroku it starts to fail with no reason or readable error. Just common error and strange message when I try to print it
[image: response]
[image: error message in console]

what looks strange for me that presigned urls are completely different when I make call from local host or from heroku
response for localhost looks like this:

```
https://mybucket.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/5e3ec346d0b5af34ef9dfadf_avatar.png?AWSAccessKeyId=<AWSKeyIdHere>&Content-Encoding=base64&Content-Type=image%2Fpng&Expires=1581172437&Signature=xDJcRBiA%2FmQF1qKhBZrnhFXWdaM%3D
```

and response for heroku deployment looks like this:

```
https://mybucket.s3.u-west-1.amazonaws.com/5e3ee2bd1513b60017d85c6c_avatar.png?Content-Type=image%2Fpng&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=<credentials-key-here>%2F20200208%2Fu-west-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20200208T163315Z&X-Amz-Expires=900&X-Amz-Signature=<someSignature>&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=content-encoding%3Bhost
```

server code is almost like in examples:

```
const Bucket = process.env.BUCKET_NAME
const region = process.env.BUCKET_REGION

AWS.config = new AWS.Config({
accessKeyId: process.env.S3_KEY,
secretAccessKey: process.env.S3_SECRET,
region,
logger: console
})

const s3 = new AWS.S3()

async function generatePutUrl(inputParams = {}) {
  const params = { Bucket, ...inputParams }
  const { Key } = inputParams    
  const putUrl = await s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', params)
  const getUrl = generateGetUrlLocaly(Key)

  return {putUrl, getUrl}
}
```

the only difference that I can imagine is SSL - I run local server VIA http and heroku goes over https by default...

but I don't understand how it may influence here.
I will appreciate any meaningful advises how to debug and fix it.
thank you.

Comment: @kkkkkkk pointed correctly. Looks like a problem with `configuration`. Please recheck your `Prod` mode configuration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like that your bucket region is incorrect. Shouldn't it be `eu-west-1` instead of `u-west-1`?

Comment: sharp eye you have:) I will check it soon

Answer (score 1):

Please update your BUCKET_REGION in environment variables at Heroku Server settings from

> u-west-1

to

> eu-west-1

and restart the dynos. It may solve your problem.